# Python Virtual Environment (virtualenv) file path logic/ errors

Tags: python, django

Trying to establish a virtual environment and tried the following command:
       `virtualenv --python=/var/bin/python --clear --no-site-packages --unzip-setuptools --setuptools ~/virtualenvs/project_name_here`

Running the above command generates the following error:

```
The executable /var/bin/python (from --python=/var/bin/python) does not exist
```

If I play around with the '--python=/var/bin/python' path, then I get the following error:

```
virtualenv: error: no such option: --/var/bin/python
```

I know I have virtualenv itself as a gem/program, because typing virtualenv by itself into the command line gives the help menu.

I am wondering if it's something to do with the path part of the command:

```
--python=/var/bin/python
```

Should I be replacing the '--python=' with an actual file path?
Where is the var/bin/python even located?
That particular portion is a mystery to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `/var/bin/python` the location of your Python executable? (What happens if you run `/var/bin/python`?) If you wish to use your default Python executable, you can simply remove the `--python=/var/bin/python ` option altogether

Comment: Ok, looks like /var/bin/python never existed, per kstenger below, /usr/bin/python **does** exist, so I switched that route in, appears to have installed correctly.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @EleanorZimmermann `/usr/bin/python` is probably the default anyway, so you can omit the whole `--python=...` thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this path instead: 
`/usr/bin/python` 
or find out the real path with

```
which python
```

Comment: When I switched out this path, it appears to have installed now.  thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. You may also want to be sure you want to just use python and not for example python2 in the case you have more than one version installed. This same command may help you find it out.