# setting up Django Virtual Env error "The executable /var/bin/python (from --python=/var/bin/python) does not exist"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I was given a project to work on and am now trying to run that project in a virtual environment.
I am new to python, but in the past, I was comfortable with the "manage.py runserver" concept.  I'm having trouble learning virtual environments.

I know that I have virtualenv installed.

My first direction given to run the virtual environment for this project was to run `virtualenv --python=/var/bin/python --clear --no-site-packages --unzip-setuptools --setuptools ~/virtualenvs/project_name`

That results in this error:

`The executable /var/bin/python (from --python=/var/bin/python) does not exist`

I already have python installed, what does this even mean?  I am also confused about this syntax, `--python=/var/bin/python`, was that a relative path that I should have switched out "python=/" for something else?  what does the "=/" actually represent?

Am I running the command in the wrong folder?  I have tried running it in both the outer project_name folder, containing a subfolder of the same name, and also, inside that subfolder (which contains the manage.py).
However, I can't find the var/bin/... paths anywhere in either folder.  Where should the bin paths be located?

Any help or insights would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Virtual Environment (virtualenv) file path logic/ errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618938/python-virtual-environment-virtualenv-file-path-logic-errors)

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to virtual environments, these are the steps I would take to install a virtual environment. I hope this helps.

**Setuptools**

First to check if you already have it installed type the following:

```
python
>>>import setuptools
```

If you get another >>> then you have it installed, otherwise you'll get an error. If you happen to blow up setuptools, here's how you reinstall it:

```
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
```

1.Download Python 2.7 egg

2.Change directory into new unzipped folder

3.Run the following command:

```
sudo sh ~/folder/you/downloaded/to/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

**Virtialenvwrapper**

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

**Setup**

1.Create your directories

```
sudo mkdir /project_name
sudo chown -R yourusername:admin /project_name
```

2.Find virtualenvwrapper.sh to use in step 3 below, check the following paths:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh 
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

3.Update your profile script (~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile) in a text editor, adding the lines below at the bottom of the file. If you don't have either of these files in your home directory, create a file named .bash_profile in your home directory.

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /insert/your/path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

4.Quit your Terminal app and restart it. You should see a bunch of folders get created when you restart it. This will only happen once.

5.Make your environment

```
mkvirtualenv django
(django)$ <- now you are in your new virtualenv
```

6.To leave your environment:

```
(django)$ deactivate
```

7.To enter your environment, quit Terminal again to reset paths so we can test our setup and move into your working directory to checkout a project:

```
workon django
(django)$ <- you are back in your environment
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that python is not installed in `/var/bin/python` on your machine. The path seems a bit odd, a more common path is `/usr/bin/python`.

One way to check where python is installed is to run `which python`. Try to replace `/var/bin/python` in the command you use when creating the virtualenv with the result from the `which` command.

Answer (score -1):

```
#Try this step by step procedure
1. open terminal
   pip install virtualenv
2. cd desktop
    desktop> virtualenv env
# A folder named env will appear on your desktop

3. desktop > cd env
#now activate the virtualenv
  desktop/env>.\Scripts\activate
# now you will see

(env)c:\...\desktop\env>
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.

Comment: this may not work for you,but it could help others,try to not generalise.

Comment: I have no doubt that it will work for others. My suggestion is simply to add more detail to your answer :) For instance, if you understand the error she/he is receiving, explain what the error is trying to tell them, they did after all ask "_I already have python installed, what does this even mean?_" I am merely suggesting that you edit your answer to add more detailed explanations of what is wrong, and what you are trying to achieve :)